# Nginx path reverse proxy to another webserver always returning root

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I have a docker setup of two containers connected to the same network. I have a Nginx reverse proxy on one of the containers that looks like this:

```
location /some/directory/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set $upstream_server foobar:1337;
    proxy pass http://$upstream_server/
}
```

This seems to work in loading the root page, but every single other asset is weirdly redirected (or cached) to the index.html. Every image, script and stylesheet is just the index.html.

Omitting the variable set and simply calling `proxy pass http://foobar:1337/` works just fine. However **I need to setup that variable to prevent nginx from failing to start up because the other container is down and it can't resolve the upstream.**

Inspecting the network traffic, it seems that the browser properly tries to get the correct assets from the correct locations, but the content of all those assets is `index.html`

Currently an access trace looks like this:

```
mydomain/some/directory/ -> foobar:1337/
mydomain/some/directory/asset.png -> foobar:1337/
mydomain/some/directory/js/my.js -> foobar:1337/
```

Which leads to every asset simply returning the index page.

I want my access to do this:

```
mydomain/some/directory/ -> foobar:1337/
mydomain/some/directory/asset.png -> foobar:1337/asset.png
mydomain/some/directory/js/my.js -> foobar:1337/js/my.js
```

Answer (score -1):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be
> determined:
>
> - When variables are used in proxy_pass:

```
location /name/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1$request_uri;
}
```

> In this case, if URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is,
> replacing the original request URI.

Comment: Changing my line to `proxy pass http://$upstream_server$request_uri` passes the subdirectory to the upstream which leads to a 404. 

I want `my.domain/some/directory/` -> `foobar:1337/`.

Not `my.domain/some/directory/` -> `foobar:1337/some/directory/`

Comment: @Nexrem use rewrite. See the docs

Comment: I added `rewrite /some/directory/(.*) $1/ break;` Which did not seem to cause a difference